# How to convert the string between numpy.array and bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert the string to bytes first, and then convert it to numpy array:

```
utf8 string -> bytes -> numpy.array
```

And then:

```
numpy.array -> bytes -> utf8 string
```

Here is the test:

```
import numpy as np

string = "any_string_in_utf8: {}".format(123456)

test = np.frombuffer(bytes(string, 'utf-8'))
print(test)
```

Here is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9055/3077694159.py in <cell line: 5>()
      3 string = "any_string_in_utf8: {}".format(123456)
      4 
----> 5 test = np.frombuffer(bytes(string, 'utf-8'))
      6 print(test)

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

How to convert the string between `numpy.array` and `bytes`?

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong. Your buffer size isn't a multiple of the element size. See [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution :

- Main `Problem` in your `Code` is that you haven't mentioned `dtype`. By default `dtype` was set as `Float` and we generally started `Conversion` from `String` that's why it was throwing `ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`.
- But If we convert the same into `unsigned int` then it will work because it can't interpret `Object`. For more refer to the `Code Snippet` given below: -

```
# Import all the Important Modules
import numpy as np

# Initialize String
utf_8_string = "any_string_in_utf8: {}".format(123456)

# utf8 string -> bytes -> numpy.array
np_array = np.frombuffer(bytes(utf_8_string, 'utf-8'), dtype=np.uint8)

# Print 'np_array'
print("Numpy Array after Bytes Conversion : -")
print(np_array)

# numpy.array -> bytes -> utf8 string
result_str = np.ndarray.tobytes(np_array).decode("utf-8")

# Print Result for the Verification of 'Data Loss'
print("\nOriginal String After Conversion : - \n" + result_str)
```

> To Know more about **np.frombuffer()**: - [Click Here !](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html)

```
# Output of the Above Code: -
Numpy Array after Bytes Conversion : -
[ 97 110 121  95 115 116 114 105 110 103  95 105 110  95 117 116 102  56
  58  32  49  50  51  52  53  54]

Original String After Conversion : - 
any_string_in_utf8: 123456
```